# Editing Privacy and Security settings via Terminal commands?

Tags: macos, command-line, privacy, screen-recording, ms-teams

We've recently pushed an update for Teams to my userbase and with the switch from the "Classic" version to the "New" Teams users will need to go into System Settings > Privacy & Security > Screen Recording and then manually add New Microsoft Teams to the allowed list of apps.

I was hoping it was something we'd be able to automate through JAMF.

I'm not sure if this is possible seeing as the "new Teams" app needs to be added instead of just toggled on within the Screen Recording section.

Can this be performed in an automated manner (perhaps a scripted command-line tool or profile) to save every single machine from having to perform this manual step?

Comment: See this [Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253767907?sortBy=best) posting for a clue of what is, _and what isn't_ possible. You don't mention which version of macOS you are running, but I'm assuming it is of a recent vintage where [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102149) will disable any attempt to modify a system setting of this importance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it strictly with Terminal commands, but once you have an MDM managed Mac, the profile installation can be triggered from the shell or pushed from the management framework.

This woks well with Jamf (and almost all other MDM) once you have devices enrolled.

The iOS / Apple feature you're looking for is called **PPPC** (Privacy Preferences Policy Control), see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/privacypreferencespolicycontrol

It can be configured by deploying a customized XML (.mobileconfig) file. You can find examples of XML payloads to enable various common apps (Teams included) here: https://github.com/poundbangbash/community-screenrecording-pppc-profile

Here's an example derived from the link above, specifically for Teams/Teams2:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>ScreenRecording policy for Privacy preferences</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>ScreenRecording Privacy Preferences Control</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>net.macadmin.community.privacy.236F3EE7-6F19-4598-90A7-A1C9649CB66E</string>
            <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
            <string>Example Org</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.TCC.configuration-profile-policy</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>236F3EE7-6F19-4598-90A7-A1C9649CB66E</string>
            <key>Services</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ScreenCapture</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Authorization</key>
                        <string>AllowStandardUserToSetSystemService</string>
                        <key>CodeRequirement</key>
                        <string>identifier "com.microsoft.teams" and anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = UBF8T346G9</string>
                        <key>Comment</key>
                        <string>Microsoft Teams</string>
                        <key>Identifier</key>
                        <string>com.microsoft.teams</string>
                        <key>IdentifierType</key>
                        <string>bundleID</string>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Authorization</key>
                        <string>AllowStandardUserToSetSystemService</string>
                        <key>CodeRequirement</key>
                        <string>identifier "com.microsoft.teams2" and anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = UBF8T346G9</string>
                        <key>Comment</key>
                        <string>New Teams</string>
                        <key>IdentifierType</key>
                        <string>bundleID</string>
                        <key>Identifier</key>
                        <string>com.microsoft.teams2</string>
                    </dict>
        </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>ScreenRecording Privacy Preferences Configuration Profile</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>net.macadmin.community.privacy.69F24D79-9A66-4399-A8F7-661495B559BD</string>
    <key>PayloadScope</key>
    <string>System</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>69F24D79-9A66-4399-A8F7-661495B559BD</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```